# CodeIgniter and Oracle database - ActiveRecord insert() is adding double quotes in query

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter framework version 2.2 with Oracle 11g database.

In database.php my config looks like this:

[image]

The database connectivity with the CodeIgniter is fine. The problem occurs when I try to insert a simple record to database using ActiveRecord of CodeIgniter. Double quotes are getting added to the tablename and column names in the query. Hence I get this error:

[image]

**My controller:**

[image]

**and the Model:**

[image]

When I try to insert data directly without insert() function, the data gets added to the database:

[image]

But I need to use the ActiveRecord's insert method.

How to get rid of the double quotes?

Comment: I worked with CI and Oracle. CI produce query with double quote for oracle and works.You should check why double quote query does not work for your Oracle db.If you want to query without double quote you can use the second approach or You need to change Active record(library) code yourself so that it does not produce double quote for table name and column name.But you should better know why double quote does not work.

Comment: There is the solution to with the code change : [http://stackoverflow.com/q/17053250/4682796](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17053250/4682796)

Comment: @huggilou I had gone through that link before.. The line of code that which needs to be replaced is not at all present in the file **oci8_driver.php**

Comment: Are you sure ? I founded it in the [official repo of CodeIgniter 2.2](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2-stable/system/database/drivers/oci8/oci8_driver.php#L602) Please check if you have the last version of CI

Comment: Oh!, I grabbed CI from [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/drivers/oci8/oci8_driver.php). @huggilou Why is it different from yours?

Comment: Oh yeah, that is because, I've downloaded the developer version of CI.

Comment: And the developer version is the [3.0.1-dev](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/CodeIgniter.php#L58)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED! The problem was in the version of CI I had downloaded. I used the latest stable version 2.2 and then modified the **oci8_driver.php** according to this link : [CodeIgniter - ActiveRecords and Oracle - configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17053250/4682796)