# CodeIgniter e Oracle - Double quotes in table name - ActiveRecords

Tags: php, oracle, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, oracle12c

I am having the following problem *(table or view not exists)*. I'm using CodeIgniter 3 and Oracle 12c.

[image]

My model:

```
public function getAll(){
      $query = $this->db->get('usr');
      return $query->result_array();
}
```

I've tried a lot and no solution has solved the problem for my case. For everyone referred to the codeIgniter 2 or older version.

If I use the following query, the code works. But I want to use ActiveRecords:

```
SELECT * FROM usr
```

This is the same problem [CodeIgniter and Oracle database - ActiveRecord insert() is adding double quotes in query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692235/codeigniter-and-oracle-database-activerecord-insert-is-adding-double-quotes). But the solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the solution: https://forum.codeigniter.com/archive/index.php?thread-47389.html

Solutions in portuguese: https://wordivino.blogspot.com/2019/01/codeigniter-e-oracle-12c-message.html

***The last post***:

---

Please, look at the SQL query generated by CI:

```
SELECT * FROM "project_users" WHERE "userid" = 'user1' AND "password" = 'iamuser1'
```

Note that the table names and table fields has double quotes, and that the reason of the issue: in a oracle SQL query, you DONT escape the name of the identifiers.

Looking in the source of CI, de base class CI_DB has a flag indicating that identifiers MUST be escaped. This is not necessary in Oracle, so i just add this attribute in system/database/drivers/oci8_diver.php...

```
var $_protect_identifiers = FALSE;
```

(If someone else want to test it, I put the line above before the method db_connect() on the OCI 8 Driver).

---

In my case, I put the variable after `class CI_DB_oci8_driver extends CI_DB {`

```
class CI_DB_oci8_driver extends CI_DB {

    var $_protect_identifiers = FALSE;
    [...]
```

---

Another way to solve this problem is by modifying `DB_driver.php` (system/database/DB_driver.php).

Find the `public function protect_identifiers`
add `$item = strtoupper($item);`
Result:

```
public function protect_identifiers($item, $prefix_single = FALSE, $protect_identifiers = NULL, $field_exists = TRUE)
 {
  $item = strtoupper($item); //linha inserida

  if ( ! is_bool($protect_identifiers))
  {
 [...]
```