# Connecting codeigniter to mysql and oracle in the same application

Tags: mysql, oracle, codeigniter

I'm using Mysql and Oracle for my CI application. I tried to connect it but I found that I cannot make a query to Oracle database. It always gave an error that the table is not exist.

I already set the database.php to something like this

```html
$active_group = 'oracle';
$active_record = true;

$db['oracle']['hostname'] = '10.10.10.1:1521/ocidb';
$db['oracle']['username'] = 'ociuser';
$db['oracle']['password'] = 'ocipass';
$db['oracle']['database'] = 'ocidb';
$db['oracle']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8';
$db['oracle']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['oracle']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['oracle']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['oracle']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['oracle']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['oracle']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['oracle']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['oracle']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['oracle']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['oracle']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'mysqldb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

In a controller, I want to query a table in oracle so I load it there.

```html
function citizen(){
  $this->load->database('oracle',true);

  $data['someone'] = $this->people_model->getPeople();
  
  $this->load->view('myview',$data);
}
```

And here is the people_model

```html
function getPeople(){
  return $this->db->get('people')->result();
}
```

When I run it, it will get error

```html
Error Number: 1146

Table 'mysqldb.people' doesn't exist

SELECT * FROM (`people`) WHERE `id` = '21111'
```

It seems that it still makes query into the mysql, while the table people is in oracle. I also have tried to load the oracle database in model instead of in controller but same result.

How can I make a query to oracle in this case. Any answer would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Check this buddy [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053250/codeigniter-activerecords-and-oracle-configuration)

Comment: One more [link](http://technovelley.blogspot.in/2014/02/codeigniter-first-application-with.html)

Comment: @Bugfixer, thanks for the links. but i'm not sure if i have a problem with the bracket like mentioned in the first link. and the second link has different case with mine. it has only oracle connection while mine has mysql and oracle

Comment: i have never user oracle and mysql together but whenever i need more than one db together i do like this in controller private $oracle;
before contruct and inside contruct like this
$this->oracle = $this->load->database('oracle',TRUE);

Comment: Then for query i use $this->oracle ->where('') like this.

Comment: Just tried it and get `Cannot access private property Mycontroller::$oracle`

Comment: can you please set `['pconnect']=false` for both configs and try again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I worked with oracle and mysql using Codeigniter.

You used `$this->load->database('oracle',true);` this should be assigned to a variable as you used 2nd parameter true.
like this

```
$oracle_db=$this->load->database('oracle',true);//connected with oracle
$mysql_db=$this->load->database('default',true);//connected with mysql
```

Now you can use these two variables for your query.Like

```
$oracle_db->get('people')->result();
```

or

```
$mysql_db->get('people')->result();
```

So finally your model should be like this(do not load database at your controller)

```
function __construct()//model construct function
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->oracle_db=$this->load->database('oracle',true);
    $this->mysql_db=$this->load->database('default',true);
}
function getPeople(){
   return $this->oracle_db->get('people')->result();
}
```

Hope you will understand. Make sure it connects with your oracle db.

My database.php for oracle was like this

```
$tns = "
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = YOUR_IP)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = YOUR_SID)
    )
  )
       ";
$db['oracle']['hostname'] = $tns;
```

Comment: thanks. it's working. and thanks for pointing out the pconnect thing by @Kamran

Comment: Type: Error

Message: Call to undefined function mysql_pconnect()
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\code\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_driver.php
getting this error while connecting to mysql db

Answer (score 1):

You have to load the database and have to use that object to query from database

```
$oracle =  $this->load->database('oracle',true);
$query = $oracle->query("SELECT * FROM people");
```

and change the pconnect flag to `false` as CI have issues maintaining the persistent connection to multiple database.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this it works for me

```
$active_group = 'oracle';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['oracle'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '192.168.0.246:1521/orcl',
    //'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 's_dev0101', 
    'password' => 's_dev0101',
    'database' => 'testdb',
    'dbdriver' => 'oci8',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE,
    'save_queries' => TRUE,
);


$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => '192.168.0.106', //192.168.0.106
    //'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'aaa',
    'password' => 'aaa',
    'database' => 'ttttt',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

In Model:

```
public $db;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->db = $this->load->database('default',true);//connected with mysql
        $oracle_db = $this->load->database('oracle',true);//connected with oracle
        var_dump($oracle_db);
    }
```