# Can't use database query in codeigniter and oracle

Tags: php, mysql, database, oracle, codeigniter

I already set up my connection to oracle 11g, I can see the log-in page, but when I proceed to log-in, no record display or I can't log-in. I tried to put code to check if I'm connected to database when loading the model. If return TRUE then Im connected, but it always return FALSE and show the echo 'No database selected'.
What would be the possible cause? Are there any differences on creating queries using mysql and oracle? Do I need to put commit on my code when selecting queries?

Here's my connection. It worked and show the default page.

database.php

```
$tnsname = '(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.112)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))';
$db['default']['hostname'] = $tnsname;
$db['default']['username'] = 'test';
$db['default']['password'] = 'testpass';
$db['default']['database'] = 'testdb';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'oci8'; //Oracle 11g
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

Here's my code selecting log-in

```
<?php

class User_db extends CI_model {

    public function get_record($username, $password) {
        if ($this->load->database('default')==FALSE)
        {
           exit('No database connection!');
        }
        $query=$this->db->get_where("tbl_user", array("username"=>$username, "password"=>md5($password)));
        if($query->num_rows()==1) {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$db['oracle']['hostname'] = '10.10.10.1:1521/ocidb';
```

have a look

[Connecting codeigniter to mysql and oracle in the same application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907355/connecting-codeigniter-to-mysql-and-oracle-in-the-same-application)

Comment: that is not working! on my case, I have been connected to server and able to see the output. I just don't know why I can't use select, insert, update or delete on my code. And trying to figure if I need to have a commit code since I'm using oracle database

Comment: did you load database on autoload

Comment: yes I did. my program is working on mysql, but have issues on using oracle

Comment: I tried to do another program and have this error... A Database Error Occurred

Error Number:

SELECT * FROM "tbl_user"

Filename: /var/www/html/test2/models/user_db.php

Line Number: 6

Comment: i think there is only some syntax errors. you can try commend exit() and see the result on the code you given.